# Is it possible to change NMAVoicePackage CountryCode to Indonesia?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, maps, here-api

I used turn-by-turn-navigation using Here API. I want to change the voice to my country. Is it possible to change the voice from English to Indonesia?

I tried using this code `voicePackage.languageCode` but it's just get-only property.

Comment: Looking at the documentation I think you need to have the voice package for your language installed first but I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the voice coverage information page here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/coverage-navigation-voices.html the Indonesian language is available for TbT navigation.

Best practice is to download the voice catalog, get the voice id for your language code and download the corresponding voice skin and install it on your system. See the detailed steps described in the user guide:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html